# Pandas Series and the `in` operator

Tags: python, pandas, series

This seems like strange and counter-intuitive behavior. Can anyone explain why this is designed like this?

```
lkup = pd.Series({'fred':'Fred','amy':'Amy'})

for n in lkup:
    print(n,' --> ',n in lkup)
>>>
Amy  -->  False
Fred  -->  False
```

Why is it giving me the *Values* instead of the keys?

```
'fred' in lkup, 'amy' in lkup
>>>> True, True
```

The reason I ask is that this actually turned out to be messing up my program while mapping values from a DataFrame to values in a Series

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['fred',1,2,3],['amy',3,4,5],['john',5,6,7],['Fred',11,12,33]], columns=['name','c1','c2','c3'])

df
>>> 
    name    c1  c2  c3
0   fred    1   2   3
1   amy     3   4   5
2   john    5   6   7
3   Fred    11  12  33


df.name.map(lkup)
>>>
0    Fred
1     Amy
2     NaN
3     NaN
```

Great - as expected since:

```
lkup.to_dict()
>>> {'amy': 'Amy', 'fred': 'Fred'}
```

but when I do

```
df[df.name.isin('lkup')].name
>>> 3 Fred
```

With DataFrames I don't have this problem.

```
for n in df:
    print(n,' --> ',n in df)
>>> 
name  -->  True
c1  -->  True
c2  -->  True
c3  -->  True
```

What is the reasoning for this contradictory logic?

Comment: Iteration over a Series loops over the values. Iteration over a DataFrame loops over the column names.

Comment: The behavior of `in` is more consistent: `item in series` is equivalent to  `item in series.index`, and `item in df` is equivalent to `item in df.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it giving me the Values instead of the keys?

Because it was programmed to make the in operator iterate over values, for display purposes, since your keys are considered the series indices.

> The reason I ask is that this actually turned out to be messing up my program while mapping values from a DataFrame to values in a Series

There are two reasons your mapping is off, first one is that the keys are case sensitive so 'fred' maps to -> 'Fred', BUT 'Fred' -> NAN since there is no index in the series.
Second one, map operates on the whole df, so if you use a key such as 'john' that is missing from the series, the mapping would be NAN.

> but when I do
>
> > df[df.name.isin('lkup')].name
> >
> > > 3 Fred

Pandas data frame isin function works quite differently from the python's in operator.
It build a matrix with matched values.
Since your values are gathered from series, they are 'Fred' and 'Amy' respectively, because iterator returns values, not the indices of the series.

Source:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html